# Do upvotes to questions on Writing Meta not result in reputation?

Tags: discussion, reputation, meta

The Help link for Writing Meta (*https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/help*) actually redirects to the help page for Writing (*https://writing.stackexchange.com/help*), so it's not possible for me to determine if there are any unique policies around the Writing Meta site specifically.

I recently posted [a question](https://writing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1593/why-is-this-site-called-writing-but-still-referred-to-as-writers-at-area-51) here on Writing Meta, and received an upvote for it, but received no notification of a reputation change—nor is such being indicated on my profile.

**Update**: This is by design for all Meta sites aside from the main [Meta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) site for Stack Exchange as a whole. It is actually mentioned in the "meta" section of the regular site's [help pages](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta)—not in the reputation section.

Since this applies to all Meta sites, the pursuit of any feature request to change it would likely be more appropriate at the global Meta site.

Mostly likely getting this information into the "reputation" section of regular site help pages, so that it's more discoverable, would be best pursued that way too.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Voting on meta sites never results in a reputation change. See [What is "meta"?](https://writing.stackexchange.com/help/whats-meta) in our site help:

> Votes on meta do not affect your reputation; your meta reputation is the same as your reputation on Writing Stack Exchange (synchronized hourly), though you earn separate badges. You must have 5 reputation to participate on meta.

In fact, nothing that happens on a meta site can affect your reputation, only mainsite activity can change your reputation. Your reputation here just permanently just reflects your mainsite reputation.

(Like it says though, you do however earn badges separately on meta sites.)

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/) is an exception: despite the "meta" name, it's implemented as a mainsite with full reputation functionality.

Comment: Thanks for the information. I wouldn't have thought to look for information about reputation on the Meta version of the site in a "meta" section of the regular site's help. (Rather than looking in the "reputation" section.)

Comment: @Jason Classic case of the help only being helpful once you know where to find it. :)

Comment: Meta can get very meta. :D